# Functions using Dictionary name and Key as argument

Tags: python

```
qualifier_2 = {'KKR' : {'Chris Lynn': 4, 
                      'Sunil Narine': 10, 
                      'Gautam Gambhir (c)': 12, 
                      'Robin Uthappa (wk)': 1, 
                      'Ishank Jaggi': 28, 
                      'Colin Grandhomme': 0,
                      'Suryakumar Yadav': 31,
                      'Piyush Chawla': 2,
                      'Nathan Coulter-Nile': 6,
                      'Umesh Yadav': 2,
                      'Ankit Rajpoot': 4,
                      'Extra runs': 7,
                      'Total batted': 10},
                'MI': {'Lendl Simmons': 3,
                      'Parthiv Patel (wk)': 14,
                      'Ambati Rayudu': 6,
                      'Rohit Sharma (c)': 26,
                      'Krunal Pandya': 45,
                      'Kieron Pollard': 9,
                      'Extra runs': 8,
                      'Total batted': 6}}
```

I want to write a function that takes dictionary and team as an argument and returns the total runs
i.e `Dictionary -> qualifier_2 and Team -> KKR/MI`

```
def total_runs(x,y):
    if x == 'qualifier_2' and y == 'KKR':
        c = sum(qualifier_2['KKR'].values())
    return c
total_runs(qualifier_2,KKR)
```

Comment: You need to attempt at your problem first, Then if you're stuck you can post your question here.

Comment: def total_runs(x,y):
    if x == 'qualifier_2' and y == 'KKR':
        c = sum(qualifier_2['KKR'].values())
    return c

total_runs(qualifier_2,KKR)

Comment: Add it to the question.

Comment: I'm a beginner to coding and I tried the above

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a function, But a way to aggregate all scores at once.
Run through the dictionary and sum the values as you go.

```
final_dict = {}
for team, scores in qualifier_2.items():
    final_dict[team] = 0 # initialize score to 0
    for player, score in scores.items():
        final_dict[team] += score # accumulate score as you loop

print(final_dict)
```

Outputs:

```
{'KKR': 117, 'MI': 117}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your function with the name of the dictionary

```
total_runs(qualifier_2,KKR)
```

Then you try to compare that to a string

```
    if x == 'qualifier_2' and ........ :
```

[Identity comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not): If you really want/need to ensure that it is the specific dictionary, change it to

```
    if x is qualifier_2 and y == 'KKR':
```

In a function, you want to use the name of the parameters used in the definition.  *Inside* your function (inside the function's scope) the dictionary you passed as the first argument has been assigned to `x` and the *key* you passed as the second argument was assigned to `y`.

```
        c = sum(x[y].values())
```

---

```
def total_runs(x,y):
    if x is qualifier_2 and y == 'KKR':
        c = sum(x[y].values())
    return c
```

Your dictionary keys are strings so you need to paa a string for that argument

```
total_runs(qualifier_2,'KKR')
```

---

Functions are used to make a process more generic so that process can be reused with different arguments/values passed to it's parameters.  While there may be some reasons to check for specific parameter values (maybe for debugging), usually it defeats the purpose of a function.

You could have written it like this:

```
def total_runs(x,y):
    c = sum(x[y].values())
    return c
```

or

```
def total_runs(x,y):
    return sum(x[y].values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values()` to get a list of the numbers, then pass it through `sum` to get the total:

```
qualifier_2 = {'KKR' : {'Chris Lynn': 4, 
                      'Sunil Narine': 10, 
                      'Gautam Gambhir (c)': 12, 
                      'Robin Uthappa (wk)': 1, 
                      'Ishank Jaggi': 28, 
                      'Colin Grandhomme': 0,
                      'Suryakumar Yadav': 31,
                      'Piyush Chawla': 2,
                      'Nathan Coulter-Nile': 6,
                      'Umesh Yadav': 2,
                      'Ankit Rajpoot': 4,
                      'Extra runs': 7,
                      'Total batted': 10},
                'MI': {'Lendl Simmons': 3,
                      'Parthiv Patel (wk)': 14,
                      'Ambati Rayudu': 6,
                      'Rohit Sharma (c)': 26,
                      'Krunal Pandya': 45,
                      'Kieron Pollard': 9,
                      'Extra runs': 8,
                      'Total batted': 6}}

def total_runs(team):
    # If team is not found in the data, return 0.
    if team not in qualifier_2:
        return 0

    # Otherwise, find the team and return a sum of their values.
    return sum(qualifier_2[team].values())

print total_runs("KKR") # Output: 117
print total_runs("MI") # Output: 117
```

You can even simplify it as a one liner, though it might be less readable:

```
def total_runs(team):
    return sum((qualifier_2.get(team) or {}).values())

print total_runs("KKR") # Output: 117
print total_runs("MI") # Output: 117
print total_runs("FOOBAR") # Output: 0
```